# How to add html codes between PHP codes without echoing?

Tags: php, html, validation

I want to set some condition and if it comes true it would show some HTML codes. Say for example a function to display mobile and web version of a website.
But echoing a whole HTML website (which has php codes in between) becomes messy.
Here's a code (Invalid PHP). What is its valid PHP?

```
<?
    function macraze() {
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge|maemo|midp|msie|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-||_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-||o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|)|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
    return 'wap';
    }
    else {
    return 'web';
    }}

    ?>
<?php
    if(macraze()=='wap') {
?>
<div>HTML Mobile Codes</div>
<?php
echo "Some PHP codes";
?>
<?php
    }
?>
<?php 
else {
?>
<div>HTML Mobile Codes</div>
<?php
echo "Some PHP codes";
?>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `valid php`?

Comment: try `if(macraze()=='wap') {` i.e. add single quote round text literals

Comment: The above PHP is invalid correct? It will give error. Isn't is?

Comment: It should report errors yes

Comment: You could try formatting your codeit so its more readable. That might help you understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that's not "inside" `<?php ... ?>` code blocks is just treated as output, e.g.:

```
<?php  echo 'foo'; ?>
bar
```

would produce `foobar` as output, just as if you'd done

```
<?php echo 'foo'; echo 'bar'; ?>
```

If you need to dump out a bunch of html conditionally, you CAN do something like

```
<?php if ($somecondition) { ?>
lots of stuff here for 'true'
<?php } else { ?>
lots of stuff here for 'false'
<?php } ?>
```

just realize that this kind of coding gets really ugly to maintain and parse, since you're jumping in/out of php mode as if you were drunk.

Comment: This was the first views i had over the question,  but it seems questionnaire needs legitimate php way

Comment: and what's an "illegitimate php way", then?

Comment: i don't think i have anything else to say above your answer

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem. I faced that too while creating my website. What i did instead was saving the two different codes in different files. eg.`codesample1.php` and `codesample2.php` and saved in a different folder named say `assets`.

now this will help reduce the messy-ness

```
if(condition)
   include('assets/codesample1.php');
else
   include('assets/codesample2.php');
```

Also it helped me through the debugging process.As the code samples were in different files, i didnt have to encounter hundreds of lines of codes to find the error.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Its better only when ur code samples are large. Else u shud write the lines directly

Comment: I was thinking of the same for creating mobile and web versions of my site. Storing the codes in /mobile/ and /web/ folders. But do you think its wise? I mean when I would want to make some changes into the site I would need to locate the files first. Or would it be better to have the codes in the same page?

Comment: i think that keeping them in different files helps because, sometimes a page can exceed 1000 lines, locating the accurate file in a folder will be easier. In addition to that, the file names are related to the kindof code u r storing in it, so personally i never had any trouble locating them

Comment: and in addition to that, you can also use the same file in different pages. For eg. I had stored the code of my navigation bar in a file named `navbar.php` so, i just used that file in all my other website pages whereever needed and if any changes need to be done, i just had to edit the `navbar` file.

Comment: if you intend to code for both mobile and web versions, fitting them in one page is not at all advisable. It might turn too large and messy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some templating engine such as [Latte](http://latte.nette.org/en/) or Twig.
You can then define templates and render what template you want with one line of code. It is XSS protected and more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

Create a php variable with your html content in it and you can reuse the code if you want.  It provides better maintainability if we seperate large html lines.

```
$var = '<html></html>'
```

Declare

```
echo $var
```

Such code can be reused using include or required to.  Making it efficient.

Comment: You can either set headers for a php html file rather than embedding code.  We see such routes in email messaging facilities

Comment: <html></html> also contsins php functions and codes. So we just cannot echo out directly. I think @MarcB is right.

Comment: Look,  there is no need for php braces if you are just outputing whole html file,  only use php html when you want code to be sent via errors,  success,  routes etc.